# How create a customize dynamic table in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, dynamic-tables

I was trying to create a customize dynamic table in reactjs with header but somehow it fails using hooks. I am new in reactjs

Here is what I tried but it fail:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Servicecharges = () => {

    const [items, setitems] = useState({
        stude: [
            { "Services": "Hire Charges for Langar / Preeti Bhoj", "Charges": "£251", "Comments": "Including use of the Kitchen. Additionally all goods and materials to be supplied or purchased from the Mandir" },
            { "Services": "Preeti Bhoj (Daal, 1 Veg, Dahi, Chawal, Roti, Sweet)", "Charges": "£321", "Comments": "Additional Sabzi (£100)Plus Cleaner (£50)" },
            { "Services": "Pooja / Havan at residences (Inside Glasgow)", "Charges": "£31+", "Comments": "" },
            { "Services": "Pooja / Havan at residences (Outside Glasgow)", "Charges": "£51+", "Comments": "" },
        ]
    })

    const renderTableData = () => {
        return this.items.stude.map((stud, index) => {
            const { Services, Charges, Comments } = stud //destructuring
            return (
                <tr >
                    <td>{Services}</td>
                    <td>{Charges}</td>
                    <td>{Comments}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 id='title'>React Dynamic Table</h1>
            <table id='students'>
                <tbody>
                    {this.renderTableData()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Servicecharges;
```

Use Servicescharges.js in your App.js

```js
render(){
    <Servicecharges />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `this` keyword since your component is a **fucntional** component

```
const renderTableData = () => {
        return items.stude.map((stud, index) => { // remove this
            const { Services, Charges, Comments } = stud //destructuring
            return (
                <tr >
                    <td>{Services}</td>
                    <td>{Charges}</td>
                    <td>{Comments}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

return (
            <div>
                <h1 id='title'>React Dynamic Table</h1>
                <table id='students'>
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                       <th>Services</th>
                       <th>Charges</th>
                       <th>Comments</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {renderTableData()} // remove this
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: hey @Sarthak Aggarwal if i remove this {renderTableData()} nothing appears, but if i use this {renderTableData()}  i get this error ×
TypeError: Unable to get property 'items' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @ParthTiwari, I have updated my code. let me know if it works or you get any error.

Comment: thanks @Sarthak Aggarwal its working, do we not use this in react hooks? but output is not same as expected as per design

Comment: @ParthTiwari, React hooks is used in your functional component which essentially is a function, and `this` refers to the call-site or where the function has been called from.
Have a look at [this](https://codeburst.io/all-about-this-and-new-keywords-in-javascript-38039f71780c) to understand more about `this`. Also updated the code for table design.

Comment: hey@Sarthak Aggarwal can you please look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210665/how-create-a-customize-list-itemli-inside-a-unorder-listul-in-reactjs