# How create a customize list item(li) inside a unorder list(ul) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to create a customize dynamic list item(li) inside ul in reactjs  but somehow it fails using hooks. It does not render anything, I am new in reactjs

i am trying to ad images to in a table and storing the images in json formate. Some how images are not displayed

Here is what I tried but it fail:

```js
    const initial_value = {        
        stude: [
        { "Message": "XYZ" , "path": "/ra" , "images" : require("../../Images/message/Baba.jpeg")},
        { "Message": "DBA", "path": "/ba" , "images" : require("../../Images/message/abaed.jpeg")},
        { "Message": "ARC", "path": "/rew"},
        { "Message": "ACH" , "path": "/ach"},
        { "Message": "The Queen" ,  "path": "/queen"}
    ]}

    const [message,setmessage] = useState(initial_value)

    const referenceData = () => {
        message.stude.map((stud,index) => {
            const { Message, Path } = stud 
            return(
                <Link to = {Path}>
                    <li><u>{Message}</u></li>
                </Link>
            )
        })
    }

const referenceImage = () => {
    return message.stude.map((stud,index) => {
        const { Images } = stud 
        return(
            <tr >
                <td className = "XYZ"><img src={require(`${Images}`)}  alt="description " /></td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}

    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col xs lg="8">
                    <h1><b>Messages</b></h1>
                    <br></br>
                    <p><span>This page contains the messages of goodwill from our sponsors and important persons, we sincerely thank all for their support and encouragement towards this sacred endeavour.</span></p>
                    <br></br>
                    <p><span>Message from:</span></p>
                    <br></br>
                    <ul>
                        {referenceData()}
                    </ul>
                </Col>
                <Col xs lg="2">
                    < Announcementandopening />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col xs lg="2">
                    <table id='students' className = "table">
                        <tbody>
                            {referenceImage()}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return from your `referenceData`

```
 const referenceData = () => {
        return message.stude.map((stud,index) => { // added return
            const { Message, Path } = stud 
            return(
                <Link to = {Path}>
                    <li><u>{Message}</u></li>
                </Link>
            )
        })
    }
```

To use images, Try this

```
import SampleImage from '../path/sampleImage.png'
```

Use it in your initial values.

```
const initial_value = {        
        stude: [
        { "Message": "XYZ" , "path": "/ra" , "images" : sampleImage,
        { "Message": "DBA", "path": "/ba" , "images" : sampleImage,
        { "Message": "ARC", "path": "/rew"},
        { "Message": "ACH" , "path": "/ach"},
        { "Message": "The Queen" ,  "path": "/queen"}
    ]}
```

Then pass the image to `src` of `<img>`

```
 const { images } = stud

 <td className = "XYZ"><img src={images}  alt="description " /></td>
```

I hope you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks @Sarthak Aggarwal return just skip from my mind do you have an idea where to study more about hooks?

Comment: @ParthTiwari, try this course at [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/share/101WbyBEIfeVhSQ34=/). You will get good idea about react.

Comment: hey @Sarthak Aggarwal if I need to save my images in json and then further can I use it as I am trying somehow it fails I have update my code

Comment: Yes you can use it but I don't think your code will work this way.

Comment: can you @Sarthak Aggarwal please help me out

Comment: @ParthTiwari sure.

Comment: What changes should I make?

Comment: @ParthTiwari I have updated my code. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot i get the gist and its working fine thankyou again

Comment: What if I am using in this way {"images" : "../../Images/message/Baba.jpeg"}, why this is not returning the image

Comment: Because that is just a string and nothing else. There is no data of image in it.